# "Pie" vs "Tart"?

Tags: pie, language

I've been told that there are some differences between a "pie" and a "tart". What's the difference, and when do I call it a pie, and when do I call it a tart?

Sorry for my English!

Comment: Your English is fine :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, a pie refers to a pastry covered with a lid, like a typical apple pie. A tart is open topped, like a quiche, or a French *tartes aux pommes*.

However, there are exceptions to this: many pies will be open topped too. Usually this is a matter of depth: the deeper it is, the more likely it is to be called a pie rather than a tart.

Regional variations also apply.

Comment: Would a tart normally be served cold, while a pie often hot? I can't recall having a hot tart

Comment: Hmmm, not necessarily. You can have hot, savoury tarts as a main meal - 'sun-dried tomato and goat's cheese tart' is almost standard-issue at vegetarian restaurants. Dessert tarts are usually cold though.

Comment: Yes, of course, I have had those, just didn't remember them as tarts (thin and open(ish) topped). I just did a quick google on **"hot tart"** to check out any good recipes, very bad mistake!

Comment: Tarte Tatin? =)

Comment: I did say there were exceptions. Although tarte tatin isn't really lidded, it's just upside down...

Answer (score 1):

It's the shape. A tart is baked in a shallow dish with straight sides; a pie dish is deeper, and has sloping sides. At least, that's the way it is in the US.